# Что такое "ручки" на сленге программистов?

Tags: терминология

Например, смотря видео с различных конференций Яндекса, можно часто слышать это слово.

> Ну в том числе у нас есть такие ручки, в том числе продуктовые ручки, когда нужно чтобы в определенный момент в браузере что-то замигало. Ну вот это не сильно нагруженные ручки. Очень нагруженные ручки мы стали писать на плюсах.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это что-то яндексоспецифическое, видимо. Ни разу не слышал слово «ручки» в таком контексте.

Comment: предположу: "инструменты", в контексте цитаты,  логично вытекает, "собственные наработки программного обеспечения". СЕО контекст - обработка некоторого объёма информации путём визуального просмотра, это объясняется спецификой некоторых тематик

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Подозреваю, это может быть как-то связано с внешним видом реализуемых компонентом интерфейсов в UML, которые выглядят как рукоятки в механике/гидравлике:

[image: UML Interface]

Соответственно, "дернуть ручку" - воспользоваться интерфейсом.

Answer (score 17):

Это термин специфичный для Яндекса, пошел от "ручек управления" - т.е. что-то, за что можно подергать, чтобы произошло какое-то действие. Часто используется в словосочетании "дернуть ручку".

К *handle* никакого отношения не имеет. К UML возможно тоже, т.к. он в документации не используется.

Comment: Кажется, это должно быть принятым ответом.

Answer (score 9):

Ручки - это, например, URL'ы в API какого-нибудь сервиса.
Вот, например, [API Яндекс.Диска](https://tech.yandex.ru/disk/api/reference/upload-docpage/).
Я могу сказать: "Чтобы загрузить файл на сервис, мне надо дёрнуть ручку
https://cloud-api.yandex.net/v1/disk/resources/upload и получить URL для закачки".

Comment: слово "ручка" в данной документации не упоминается

Answer (score 4):

Ручка - это просто метод публичного интерфейса приложения, будь то веб-приложение или еще какое-то. Пошло от английского handle, насколько понимаю, используется со времен `handle = fopen(path, mode);`. Очевидно, в тексте речь идет про какие-то ресурсы публичного API, которые вследствие высокой нагрузки переписали на плюсах для увеличения быстродействия.

Comment: видать орусифицирование английского handle

Comment: @des1roer "Пошло от английского handle"